# Custom JQuery Lightbox doesn't work on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, lightbox

When I run the code offline using a HTML code and calling the JQuery Library, it works properly. However, when I try to implement it on my WordPress site, it simply doesn’t work.

**1)**  I added the script code to the footer of my template (a)

**2)**  I called the JQuery library on the header of my template (b) I also tried to test different combinations but I had no success.

**3)**  The CSS classes were added to my template CSS file. (c)

**4)**  I declared the class that start the instructions on the button ( the one I want to start the light box)

Could anyone help me to understand what could be wrong and how to solve it?

Many thanks!

---

(a) Script added to the footer

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.lightbox').click(function() {
            $('.background-map-lightbox, .map-lightbox').animate({'opacity':'.60'}, 500, 'linear');
            $('.map-lightbox').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 500, 'linear');
            $('.background-map-lightbox, .map-lightbox').css('display','block');

        });

        $('.close-map-lightbox').click(function() {

            $('.map-lightbox, .background-map-lightbox').animate({'opacity':'.0'}, 500, 'linear', function() {
                $('.map-lightbox, .background-map-lightbox').css('display','none');

                });

        });

        $('.background-map-lightbox').click(function() {

            $('.map-lightbox, .background-map-lightbox').animate({'opacity':'.0'}, 500, 'linear', function() {
                $('.map-lightbox, .background-map-lightbox').css('display','none');

                });

        });

    });

</script>
```

(b) On the header of the template

```
//test 1
<?php wp_enqueue_script ("jquery");?>

//test 2
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(c) CSS

```
.lightbox {
    color:green;

}

.background-map-lightbox{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:.0;
    -moz-opacity:.0;
    filter:alpha (opacity=0);
    z-index:100;
    display:none;

}

.map-lightbox {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-left: 13px solid #eba096;
  border-radius: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
  color: black;
  display: none;
  height: 303px;
  left: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 540px;
  z-index: 101;
}

.close-map-lightbox {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#a6d5b3;
    border:solid 1px #e6e6e6;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    top:-27px;
    right:-27px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;

}

#map-ebook-title h1 {
  color: #8a8198;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 62px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 43px;
  margin: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#map-ebook-title h2 {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-family: "Open Sans Semibold";
  font-size: 23px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 43px;
  margin: 30px 15px;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get in console?

Comment: ... quote @msbodetti - have you some error? Is the jquery library correctly loaded? tries to use `console.log()` or some breakpoints in your javascript to know if the script was fired.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress jQuery uses non-conflict. The method i use is to swop '$' for the word jQuery.

Using Chrome, If you click f12 on any element on the screen there is a option to inspect element, click on this and then console on the new screen that pops up. It will show you JS errors.